error during backing up my pc with windows 11 on external drive?
error encountered
I'm trying to back up my Windows 11 system using the Control Panel, but I'm encountering an error (0x800700E1) stating that the operation did not complete because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software. How can I fix this?
